# "vital" components of AJAX -- XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax

This is to ask for verification-- and further info/reference if i'm wrong:

AJAX is the asynchronous go-between between the server and the client-- the operations that 
are not bound to loading&reloading the web-pages.

From what i know, it's the class **XMLHttpRequest** handling all this asynchronousity-- all the methods and members (**send(), onreadystatechange,** etc.) handling/helping 
the asynch operations are on **XMLHttpRequest**.

is this all in AJAX-- as far as its significant components go? 
from what i see, **XMLHttpRequest** is the only vital thing in AJAX.

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. XMLHttpRequest is what's really the core of the ajax architecture. In a modern web app, it's most likely to be hidden under the hood ( jQuery or another javascript framework/lib ).

I remember using XMLHttpRequest for my ajax stuff like 5-6 years ago and it wasnt very user friendly but it was working.

Jquery encapsulate the XMLHttpRequest object within some methods, like get and ajax.

These methods also simplify the way the parameters are sent to and received from the server. (xml/json)

The server side part of the ajax operation is not tied to any technology. Which means you can have PHP, C# WCF/ASMX Services or something else to do the server side work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [this](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp) or [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml) for complete references for the XMLHttpRequest object.